# Comparing Arrays for Accuracy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've a 2 arrays:

```
np.array(y_pred_list).shape
# returns (5, 47151, 10)
np.array(y_val_lst).shape
# returns (5, 47151, 10)

np.array(y_pred_list)[:, 2, :]
# returns 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

np.array(y_val_lst)[:, 2, :]
# returns
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

I would like to go through all 47151 examples, and calculate the "accuracy". Meaning the sum of those in y_pred_list that matches y_val_lst over 47151. What's the comparison function for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
accuracy = (y_pred_list == y_val_lst).all(axis=(0,2)).mean()
```

...though since your arrays are clearly floating-point arrays, you might want to allow for numerical-precision errors rather than insisting on exact equality:

```
accuracy = (numpy.abs(y_pred_list - y_val_lst) < tolerance ).all(axis=(0,2)).mean()
```

(where, for example, `tolerance = 1e-10`)

The `.all(axis=(0,2))` call records cases in which everything in its input is `True` (i.e. everything matches) when working along the dimension 0 (i.e. the one that has extent 5) and dimension 2 (the one that has extent 10). It outputs a one-dimensional array of length 47151.  The `.mean()` call then gives you the proportion of matches in that sequence, which is my best guess as to what you mean by "over 47151".

Comment: Thanks! May I know what's .all(axis=0) and .all(axis=-1) doing? I understand it may be returning True but I'm confused with the axis and double .all().

Comment: @Ritchie it can be done more elegantly/understandably with a single `.all()` call specifying multiple `axis` values at once. See edited edits.

Answer (score 6):

You can find a lot of useful classification scores in `sklearn.metrics`, particularly `accuracy_score()`. See the [doc here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html), you would use it as:

```
import sklearn
acc = sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(np.array(y_val_list)[:, 2, :], 
                                     np.array(y_pred_list)[:, 2, :])
```

Comment: sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score cant handle multilabel datasets like this.